# Display latitude and longitude with multiple JSON Data in Map in swift 3?

Tags: json, swift3, mapkit

I am not Able to Display multiple JSON Data with latitude and Longitude using Alamofire in mapView.Normal Static Array is displayed in MapView but Dynamic Data are not being Displayed in Map.How can this issue be solved?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class NearbyViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    var schoolMap : [schools] = []
    var scholmap : schools?

    let locations = [
        ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
        ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
        ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
    ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       getschoolMapJson()
        getmapSchool()


        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }

    override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     mapview.reloadInputViews()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       mapview.reloadInputViews()
    }

   func getmapSchool(){

        for locationn in schoolMap{
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((locationn.latitude) , (locationn.longitude))
            print("lati",locationn.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0, 10.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = locationn.name
            print("namelati",locationn.name)
        mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }


    func getschoolMapJson(){
        if (schoolMap.count > 0){
            return
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/schools")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print("success api",data)
                let myresponse = JSON(data)

                /*for i in 0..<self.myresponse.count{
                 let schools_data = schools(schoolJson:self.myresponse[i])
                 self.schooldata.append(schools_data)

                 }*/
                for school in myresponse.array!{
                    let schoolsObj = schools(schoolJson: school)
                    self.schoolMap.append(schoolsObj)
                    debugPrint(schoolsObj)
                }
//                self.mapview.reloadInputViews()
            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aknkb.jpg)

> Why i am not able to display the Dynamic Data.How can this issue be
>   solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with below code :

```
for school in myresponse.array!{
    let schoolsObj = schools(schoolJson: school)

    //Add Pin
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((schoolsObj.latitude) , (schoolsObj.longitude))
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0, 10.0)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = locationn.name
    mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)

    self.schoolMap.append(schoolsObj)

    }
```

Relpace this in your `getschoolMapJson()`

Hope this will work

Comment: code works but it is displaying blue screen i.e means it is showing the ocean using simulator

Comment: check latitude and logitude coming in api. Or check via passing true loactions

Comment: I have used postman .the API is showing correct Latitude and Longitude

Comment: check `schoolsObj.latitude & schoolsObj.longitude`. Is it getting locations from schoolObj or not?

Comment: Latitude is showing 27.11 in log but it is showing in ocean.

Comment: Try it by passing static but true location so you will get your issue

Comment: Okay. Then my code is right na? You should have to get all correct locations from API and then you can solve it.

Comment: yes man.Thats seems it is correct.It is fixed now.thanks alot.Happy Coding